# Primefaes Calendar time avoid uncessary click

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm doing project in primefaces.I included calendar in my project.I choose id=date it will display in textbox and I select datetime select but outside click calendar is hide.I try this below code:

```
<h:form>
.........
<p:calendar id="date" value="#{calendarView.date1}" pattern="dd/mm/yyyy"/
<p:calendar id="datetime" value="#{calendarView.date2}" pattern="dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm " />
</h:form>
```

My doubt is id=date automatically hide calendar and  select   datetime select to calendar automatically not hide. Because i want avoid to uncessary click.

Comment: Can you please try to make the issue more clear. I fail to understand the actual 'problem'

Comment: When I choose time calendar it will outside click  calendar only hide.But it will not occur in normal calendar. When I select date it will automatically hide and display with same one i need in time calendar also